# Is it possible to access other apps' files in iOS/Android/Windows Phone?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

I am thinking that if possible to access other apps' folder in iOS? For example, I installed X application and I want to access X's files?

I know that ios doesnt allow it, but if a jailbreaked device?
And the same question for android? do i need root to access another app's files?
And the same question is for windows phone?

Comment: You need root on Android.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer for Android is No (unless you have root access) and according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html):

> Android is a privilege-separated operating system, in which each application runs with a distinct system identity (Linux user ID and group ID). Parts of the system are also separated into distinct identities. Linux thereby isolates applications from each other and from the system.

I don't know much about the iOS and Windows phone permissions, but it would be natural if they don't give you access to that freely. you'll probably have to JailBreak.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you cannot access the Local Storage of the App not even via PC or file manager. All the App data is sandboxed you can only access the known locations like Pictures Library, Music,Video,Doc,SD Card.